# Tool for profiling an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, profiler

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and I'm starting to have performance problems, so I's like to start using a profiler. Since it's an eclipse plugin and not an ordinary java program, what tool should I use to profile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find JProfiler to be really helpful. It has Eclipse integration, although it is not an Eclipse plugin per sa', so you can very easily invoke a profiler instead of a regular execution session. It had very good bottleneck analysis and you can find-tune the settings to lower the overheads of the profiler itself. Highly recommended.

Comment: Ok, works fine and even installs eclipse plugins automatically (I'm using the 10 days evaluation version).

Comment: Yep, if you like it, might be worth a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your application is causing your system to run out of handles I suggest running sleak http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/sleak.htm. It's pretty easy to use and worth performing a sanity check now and then anyway.

Comment: No, the problem was that loading one big file took > 1 second and it was (unnecessarely) loaded over and over again... But thanks for the hint anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I tried different ones in the past, they didn't have the same rich functionality and ease of use for investigating long running processes or huge dumps like [Yourkit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/home/index.jsp).

Should your plugin be open source, then you can get the full version under a no cost license for that project.